# How to Make Select All Check Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I want when i click select all then all checkbox will selected and when I click again all checkbox will deselect.

but when I click it nothing happen.

my code

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/qa2fkpyv/2/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#check-all").click(function() {
    var check = $(this).attr('checked');
    if (check == "checked") {
      $("#deleteid").attr('checked', 'checked');
    } else
      $("#deleteid").removeAttr('checked');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="sort_select_delete_form" method="get">

  <div class="btn-group">
    <a href="#check-all" class="btn btn-primary" id="check-all">Select All</a>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete Selected">
  </div>

  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="1000000001" id="deleteid[]" name="deleteid[]">select1
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="1000000002" id="deleteid[]" name="deleteid[]">select2
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="1000000003" id="deleteid[]" name="deleteid[]">select3
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="1000000004" id="deleteid[]" name="deleteid[]">select4
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="1000000005" id="deleteid[]" name="deleteid[]">select5

</form>
```

Comment: id's (and names) are meant to be unique. Use a class instead or give your id's unique id's.

Comment: `check-all` has no `checked` attribute, it's a link not a checkbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Anchors do not have a checked attribute - I use a data-attribute here
2. You must have unique IDs or not use them - I use "starts-with" on the name attribute instead

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#check-all").on("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // cancel link
    var check = $(this).data("checked")==true;
    $(this).data("checked",!check);
    $("[name^='deleteid']").prop('checked', !check);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="sort_select_delete_form" method="get">

  <div class="btn-group">
    <a href="#check-all" class="btn btn-primary" id="check-all">Select All</a>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete Selected">
  </div>

  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="1000000001" name="deleteid[]">select1
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="1000000002" name="deleteid[]">select2
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="1000000003" name="deleteid[]">select3
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="1000000004" name="deleteid[]">select4
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="1000000005" name="deleteid[]">select5

</form>
```

3. Why not use a checkbox for select all?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#check-all").on("click",function(e) {
    $("[name^='deleteid']").prop('checked', this.checked);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="sort_select_delete_form" method="get">

  <div class="btn-group">
    <label for="check-all"><input type="checkbox" class="btn btn-primary" id="check-all">Select All</label>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete Selected">
  </div>

  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="1000000001" name="deleteid[]">select1
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="1000000002" name="deleteid[]">select2
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="1000000003" name="deleteid[]">select3
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="1000000004" name="deleteid[]">select4
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="1000000005" name="deleteid[]">select5

</form>
```

Comment: i like using button... btw thanks for solvet my problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
$(function(){ 
 $('#check-all').click(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('checked')){
   $(this).removeClass('checked').text('Select All');
   $('.form-check-input').prop('checked', false);
  }else{
   $(this).addClass('checked').text('Unselect All');
   $('.form-check-input').prop('checked', true);
  }
  return false;
 }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="sort_select_delete_form" method="get">

  <div class="btn-group">
 <a href="#check-all" class="btn btn-primary" id="check-all">Select All</a>
  </div>

  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="1000000001" id="deleteid1" name="deleteid[]">select1
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="1000000002" id="deleteid2" name="deleteid[]">select2
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="1000000003" id="deleteid3" name="deleteid[]">select3
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="1000000004" id="deleteid4" name="deleteid[]">select4
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="1000000005" id="deleteid5" name="deleteid[]">select5

</form>
```